# Excel FIND formula with 'OR' statement does not work when a [start_num] is introduced

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an unusual situation when trying to return the position of either an 'r' or an 's' in a cell (the value I'm finding isn't really relevant, but the behaviour of the formula is).

My Formulae is:

- =FIND({"r","s"}, B2,70)
- =FIND({"r","s"}, B3,70)

My Strings (in cell B2, B3) are:

- C:\Files\2020-01-20_First_Files_For_Processing\11223-000-3AA-CCC1-00001r000.pdf
- C:\Files\2020-01-20_First_Files_For_Processing\11223-000-3AA-CCC1-00001s001r000.pdf

The position returned for the first string (B2) is 72 - 'r', which is correct.
The position returned for the second string (B3) is 76 - 'r', which is not what I want.  I want it to find the first character of either 'r' or 's', whichever appears first in the string, which in this case should be 's' for the second string in cell B3.

If I switch the r and s around in the formula to be:

- =FIND({"s","r"}, B2,70)
- =FIND({"s","r"}, B3,70)

The first string formula (B2) returns #VALUE (an obvious failure) and the second string (B3) returns position 72, which is what I want.  Obviously the 2 are conflicting with each other.

I would be grateful if anyone could let me know whether there is a way to make this work?

Comment: Is it necessary to find the position of the symbol or is it enough to determine its existence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following formulas-
for existence:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND({"r","s"},A1,12)))>0
```

for position of first char:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MIN(--IFERROR(FIND({"r","s"},A1,12),10^10)))
```

Sample (in B col is your formula):
[image]

Comment: Excellent - that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you...